# How to fill different values in a new column based on different values of another column using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is my data:

```
a <- data.frame(x=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'),
                y=c('Yes','No','No','Yes','No','No'),
                z=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

I want to generate a new column this way:

1. Group by `x`, so all the `A`s will be in one group and all `B`s in another
2. For every group, if `y=Yes`, then keep the `z` value in the new column. If `y=No`, then using the `z` value with `y=Yes`.

So, the new data should look like this:

```
x    y   z   z1
A   Yes  1   1
A   No   2   1
A   No   3   1
B   Yes  4   4
B   No   5   4
B   No   6   4
```

I can use this way to do:

```
a1 <- a %>%
   filter(y=='Yes') %>%
   distinct(x,y,z)
 a2 <- a %>%
    left_join(a1,by='x') %>%...
```

But in this way, I have to generate `a1` as an intermediate. How to do this just in one pipeline without generating a new variable like `a1` in my example?

Comment: Just write the `z1` value with the first `z/Yes` value - `a %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(z1 = first(z[y=="Yes"]))` - though this will not work appropriately if you have multiple `z/Yes`'s - the join is probably safer in some respects in that you will see if you get many-to-one results.

Comment: This is good. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine both pipelines and perform the same functions in one shot.

i.e...

```
    a <- data.frame(x=c('A','A','A','B','B','B'),
                    y=c('Yes','No','No','Yes','No','No'),
                    z=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))

    a %>% left_join(a %>% filter(y=='Yes') %>% distinct(x,y,z), by='x') %>% select(-y.y)
```

This results in duplicate columns tagged with .x and .y as a result of the join.